# haskell: how to get list of numbers which are higher then their neighbours in a starting list

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to learn Haskell and I want to solve one task. I have a list of Integers and I need to add them to another list if they are bigger then both of their neighbors. For Example:
I have a starting list of [0,1,5,2,3,7,8,4] and I need to print out a list which is [5, 8]

This is the code I came up but it returns an empty list:

```
largest :: [Integer]->[Integer]
largest n
   | head n > head (tail n) = head n : largest (tail n)
   | otherwise = largest (tail n)
```

Comment: How about you solve this in two steps - 1. Make a new list that is a tuple of the element, left neighbor, and right neighbor. 2. Filter that list for tuples where the middle elements is largest and project out the middle element.

Comment: Also, what happens with `[0,1]` do we get `[1]` or `[]` or something else?

Comment: for [0,1] it should return [1]

Comment: @dziulis: then shouldn't `[0,1,5,2,3,7,8,4]` result in `[5,8,4]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, because 4 is smaller than 8

Comment: Hint: look what `let (x:y:ls) = [0,1,5,2,3,7,8,4] in zip3 (x:y:ls) (y:ls) ls` gives in the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this as outlined by Thomas M. DuBuisson. Since we want the ends of the list to "count", we'll add negative infinities to each end before creating triples. The [monoid-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html#t:NegInf) package provides a suitable type for this.

```
import Data.Monoid.Inf

pad :: [a] -> [NegInf a]
pad xs = [negInfty] ++ map negFinite xs ++ [negInfty]

triples :: [a] -> [(a, a, a)]
triples (x:rest@(y:z:_)) = (x,y,z) : triples rest
triples _ = []

isBig :: Ord a => (a,a,a) -> Bool
isBig (x,y,z) = y > x && y > z

scnd :: (a, b, c) -> b
scnd (a, b, c) = b

finites :: [Inf p a] -> [a]
finites xs = [x | Finite x <- xs]

largest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
largest = id
    . finites
    . map scnd
    . filter isBig
    . triples
    . pad
```

It seems to be working appropriately; in ghci:

```
> largest [0,1,5,2,3,7,8,4]
[5,8]
> largest [10,1,10]
[10,10]
> largest [3]
[3]
> largest []
[]
```

You might also consider merging `finites`, `map scnd`, and `filter isBig` in a single list comprehension (then eliminating the definitions of `finites`, `scnd`, and `isBig`):

```
largest :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
largest xs = [x | (a, b@(Finite x), c) <- triples (pad xs), a < b, c < b]
```

But I like the decomposed version better; the `finites`, `scnd`, and `isBig` functions may turn out to be useful elsewhere in your development, especially if you plan to build a few variants of this for different needs.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might try is lookahead.  (Thomas M. DuBuisson suggested a different one that will also work if you handle the final one or two elements correctly.) Since it sounds like this is a problem you want to solve on your own as a learning exercise, I’ll write a skeleton that you can take as a starting-point if you want:

```
largest :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
largest [] = _
largest [x] = _ -- What should this return?
largest [x1,x2] | x1 > x2   = _
                | x1 < x2   = _
                | otherwise = _
largest [x1,x2,x3] | x2 > x1 && x2 > x3 = _
                   | x3 > x2 = _
                   | otherwise = _
largest (x1:x2:x3:xs) | x2 > x1 && x2 > x3 = _
                      | otherwise          = _
```

We need the special case of `[x1,x2,x3]` in addition to `(x1:x2:x3:[])` because, according to the clarification in your comment, `largest [3,3,2]` should return `[]`. but `largest [3,2]` should return `[3]`. Therefore, the final three elements require special handling and cannot simply recurse on the final two.

If you also want the result to include the head of the list if it is greater than the second element, you’d make this a helper function and your `largest` would be something like `largest (x1:x2:xs) = (if x1>x2 then [x1] else []) ++ largest' (x1:x2:xs)`.  That is, you want some special handling for the first elements of the original list, which you don’t want to apply to all the sublists when you recurse.

Comment: I think you meant to use `largest (x2 : x3 : xs)` in your example of the last case? A way to structure the code to avoid this issue is to phrase the last pattern as `x1 : xs@(x2 : x3 : _)` then recur with just `largest xs`.

Comment: @JonPurdy No, the idea there is that we need to add the first element if it is larger than the second, but in the recursive helper, we never add the first element `x1`. The recursive helper compares `x2` to both `x1` and `x3`, and never adds `x1`. So we call it on the *original* list.

Comment: @JonPurdy However, the `x1:@xs(x2:x3:_)` syntax works fine, and might be less error-prone. Good suggestion.

Comment: Ah, I see what you’re getting at, that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, one approach would be to first group the list into tuples of length 3 using Preludes [`zip3`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=zip3) and [`tail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:tail):

```
*Main> let xs = [0,1,5,2,3,7,8,4]
*Main> zip3 xs (tail xs) (tail (tail xs))
[(0,1,5),(1,5,2),(5,2,3),(2,3,7),(3,7,8),(7,8,4)]
```

Which is of type: `[a] -> [b] -> [c] -> [(a, b, c)]` and `[a] -> [a]` respectively.

Next you need to find a way to filter out the tuples where the middle element is bigger than the first and last element. One way would be to use Preludes [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) function:

```
*Main> let xs = [(0,1,5),(1,5,2),(5,2,3),(2,3,7),(3,7,8),(7,8,4)]
*Main> filter (\(a, b, c) -> b > a && b > c) xs
[(1,5,2),(7,8,4)]
```

Which is of type: `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. This filters out elements of a list based on a Boolean returned from the predicate passed.

Now for the final part, you need to extract the middle element from the filtered tuples above. You can do this easily with Preludes [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) function:

```
*Main> let xs = [(1,5,2),(7,8,4)]
*Main> map (\(_, x, _) -> x) xs
[5,8]
```

Which is of type: `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. This function maps elements from a list of type `a` to `b`.

The above code stitched together would look like this:

```
largest :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
largest xs = map (\(_, x, _) -> x) $ filter (\(a, b, c) -> b > a && b > c) $ zip3 xs (tail xs) (tail (tail xs))
```

Note here I used typeclass `Ord`, since the above code needs to compare with `>` and `<`. It's fine to keep it as `Integer` here though.